# Get the IDs of all the controls of Office 2010 ribbon and interact with ribbon shortcut from custom Add-ins

Tags: .net, vsto, powerpoint, add-in, ribbonx

I want to get all the controls list in the powerpoint 2010 ribbon like the one in the powerpoint option -> customize ribbon-> all commands.

Furthermore, I want to interact with ribbon shortcut from **custom** Add-ins

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673502/add-standard-command-button-new-slide-to-custom-ribbon-in-office-add-in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find all office id's you want on microsoft website http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627.

You will find your id's in `PowerPointControls.xlsx` file.

For create you own menu :

Open your Ribbon.xml

And add following after `<ribbon>`

```
<tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="ContentGroup" label="Content">
            <button id="textButton" label="Insert Text"
                 screentip="Text" onAction="OnTextButton"
                 supertip="Inserts text at the cursor location."/>
            <button id="tableButton" label="Insert Table"
                 screentip="Table" onAction="OnTableButton"
                 supertip="Inserts a table at the cursor location."/>
        </group>
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

For a custom addin shortcut, I think you have to add a new tab :

```
<tab id="YourTab" visible="true" label="Name">
    <group id="YourGroup" label="name">
      <button onAction="CallAddinsHere();" label="Call add-ins"/>
    </group>
  </tab>
```

If you want to interact with custom addin shortcut, have a look at :

[Automate Office Ribbon through MSAA (CSOfficeRibbonAccessibility)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSOfficeRibbonAccessibility-cd7fe67f/view/Reviews)

Comment: Thank you but the thing is there are some custom addins also present in the ribbon. i want to create shortcuts for those controls also

Comment: Sorry I think, my question is not clear. Actually I want to create shortcuts for ribbon buttons and commands like "Align Top", for microsoft inbuilt commands i know how to do that. but there are some controls that is from some other com-addin. which i cant able to access using my addin.

Comment: @user1579375 Check now (again)

Comment: @user1579375 : At least, I find it ! :D please validate my answer :)

Comment: Rokr_13 - can you please add some code that shows how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Rokr_13 : the code you want is already in the answer. What else do you want ?

Comment: Alternatively, has anyone hacked the list of  idMSO names and ordinals and published them in plaintext somewhere? Downloadable .exe files are unusable for developers working in a corporate environment.

Comment: **Update** Some dissident in Redmond has published the list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd909393(v=office.12).aspx) and the button images are named [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd953682(v=office.12).aspx)  Don't be fooled by the 'empty page' - the script that serves the text takes a couple of seconds to run.