# Add standard command button "New Slide" to custom ribbon in office add-in

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, add-in, ribbonx

I have created my **customized ribbon** in an addIn. Now I would like to add the **New Slide command** that exist in home screen (see screenshot below).

[image: Original Powerpoint ribbon]

Comment: if you want to customize ribbon for PowerPoint You can create AddIn Project for PowerPoint.

Comment: @ShariqueAnsari:  I have created an addin I  want to call this new slide that is on home page to my Add in ribbon that is created . i want to use this feature in my add in so users wont have to move back and forth to other ribbons. with additional features given

Comment: new slide that is on home page?? Can u share your code it will help us to understand better.

Comment: You can add to quick access toolbar by right clicking on that button,it will be more easy why you want to add it in menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can add built-in controls to your custom tab by soecifying their IdMso values. See [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798) .

You can read more about the Ribbon UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think after a lot of searching I finally figured it out!
This is all the code you need, delete everything else
This will create a new slide button just like the one that comes default in PowerPoint

```
<group id="add_slide" label="Add Slide">
  <control idMso="SlideNewGallery" size="large" />
</group>
```

[credit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49ab393a-796a-4d65-9632-a99b27a51e1e/ribbonxml-menu-location-question?forum=vsto)

Answer (score 0):

i currently have new slide button in my addin like the image below which gives me a new slide[image]

however I want the option like the already existing new slide in home ribbon where I can choose templates.Is there any way to invoke this button in my customized ribbon so below is my newslide that is what i want to get in my addin

[image]

```
  private void New_slide_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

        PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("SlideNewGallery");
    }
```

Comment: As I wrote above, you need to find the built-in control ID in the [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798) and specify it for the idMso property of the custom control.

Comment: check the above edited answer i have added execute mso to new slide button.  But it just adds new slide. i want even drop down option like shownin img 2

Comment: Maybe this shall not be a comment but updated in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new **ribbon based on xml Template** in VS. Afterwards I added a group and a control based on an **idMso-Value**. When using this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tab0" label="AddIn">
        <group id="grpCustom">
          <button idMso="SlideNew" size="large" label="YOUR CUSTOM TEXT"></button>
        </group>
        <group idMso="GroupSlides"></group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

This results in that custom ribbon. [Eugene Astafiev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603351/eugene-astafiev) pointed it out, you can find [idMso-Values in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd945681(v=office.12).aspx).

[image: customized ribbon controls]

Comment: i am using designer so i added a button .. gave OfficeImageid as idmso so this creates an image of button juzt like it exists in home . and also on execute when i give this query  private void New_slide_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

        PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("SlideNewGallery");
    }      it works great.My problem is the dropdown option in new slide to select template like it is shown in 2nd image of my 2nd answer  is what i want.

Comment: There is a good article about **Understanding Custom Layouts** on [mvps.org](http://skp.mvps.org/2007/ppt003.htm). You can find there how to get the current available layouts. Unfortunatelly I failed on adding them dynamically to a splitButton....

Comment: Somehow the code and the screenshot do not like consistent? I can not see the code for the button "Neue Folie"

Comment: Using idMso is the right solution. Thanks! I like to use the Ribbon Editor to edit the ribbon http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [Franz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28751413/2043349) the solution is to use the idMso.
For the New Slide command you are looking for, if you look at MSN in the [idMso Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd953379(v=office.12).aspx) for "New Slide" you will find two entries.
The one you are looking for is a **Gallery** with idMso=SlideNewGallery.
(not a button).
You can add it in the XML. I like to use the [Ribbon Editor](http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm).
With the Ribbon Editor it looks like this:
[image: Ribbon Editor: Add idMso command]

And in the Add-In it looks then like this:
[image: AddIn Ribbon with standard command]

The CustomUI XML relevant part looks like this

```
<group id="TD_GrpMisc" label="Misc">            
        <gallery 
            idMso="SlideNewGallery"
            size="large"/>
        <button 
            idMso="SlideNew"
            size="large"/>
</group >
```